What is the best way to use Gaussian Processes to approximate highly non-stationary functions?
Gaussian process regression has trouble approximating functions with "kinks". So, what is the most widely used method to deal with this problem? I have found many proposed methods, including the neutral network kernel, deep GP networks, and warping the input space. So, I was wondering what the most practical method to deal with this problem is.

it's going to depend pretty heavily on the type of function you're interested in. this is almost like asking "what's the best way to approximate nonlinear functions?". What do you mean exactly by kinks?

To add to @JohnMadden's comment: And how are "kinks" related to highly(??) non-stationary? E.g. the white noise kernel is stationary but arguably quite kinky.

Thank you all for your replies. I guess my descriptions are indeed not rigorous enough. What I have in mind is something like the 2-D step function: f(x1, x2) = 1{x1>0}.

I see, we would think of this as a discontinuity problem rather than a nonstationarity problem. I would recomment a treed Gaussian process (https://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.4536) which is implemented by the R package tgp (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tgp/index.html). Incidentally, I am highly interested in discontinuous functions, and would be really grateful if you could share more about your use case.

Of course, I am exploring the use of GPR to solve some dynamic programming problems. I have a value function with three state variables ( V(x_1, x_2, x_3) ) with some discontinuities along the dimension of ( x_3 ). That is, the function is defined as follows:
V(x1,x2,x3)=af(x1,x2) * 1_{0≤x3<0.5} +bf(x1,x2) * 1_{0.5≤x3<0.7} +cf(x1,x2) *1_{0.9≤x3≤1.0}
